# Share a wifi connection via another wifi connection

Tags: macos, wifi, internet-sharing

Having just recently discovered how easy it is to share a wifi connection via Ethernet, I wondered whether I could plug in another wifi USB stick and get another "WLAN" entry on this screen (my apologies it's in German)

[image]

which would allow me to select it in the dropdown on the left here:

[image]

Unfortunately I was not succesful with the USB wifi stick I had at hand (it is capable of creating a hosted network - at least on Windows and on my Raspberry).

What do I have to do what I want to achieve with OS capabilities preferably?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the wifi dongle was not fully compatible/supported by Mac OS. For instance with [this dongle](https://www.2direct.de/netzwerk-technik/wireless-lan/adapter/2526/wireless-n150-mbit/s-usb-adapter-ultra-nano-size?c=62) it works as expected after installing the drivers.